# Group by Date and count of unique users as column name

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Dataframe

```
d = {'logdate': ['2022-06-20' , '2022-06-21' , '2022-06-22' , '2022-06-23' , '2022-06-24' , '2022-06-25' , '2022-06-26' , '2022-06-27' , '2022-06-28' , '2022-06-29' , '2022-06-30' , '2022-07-01' , '2022-06-20' , '2022-06-21' , '2022-06-22' , '2022-06-23' , '2022-06-24' , '2022-06-25' , '2022-06-26' , '2022-06-27' , '2022-06-28' , '2022-06-29' , '2022-06-30' , '2022-07-01'], 'Username': [ 'UserA' , 'UserA' , 'UserB' , 'UserF' , 'UserA' , 'UserA' , 'UserC' , 'UserA' , 'UserA' , 'UserE' , 'UserA' , 'UserD' , 'UserA' , 'UserE' , 'UserB' , 'UserA' , 'UserF' , 'UserE' , 'UserA' , 'UserA' , 'UserB' , 'UserB' , 'UserA' , 'UserD']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output:

```
| logdate    | Username |
|------------|----------|
| 2022-06-20 | UserA    |
| 2022-06-21 | UserA    |
| 2022-06-22 | UserB    |
| 2022-06-23 | UserF    |
| 2022-06-24 | UserA    |
| 2022-06-25 | UserA    |
```

I want to achieve the following, group by date and count of each users as individual columns

**Expected**:

```
| logdate    | UserA | UserB | UserC | UserD | UserE | UserF |
|------------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 2022-06-20 | 2     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 2022-06-21 | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 2022-06-22 | 0     | 2     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 2022-06-23 | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
```

All I could try was to group by logdate and count Username

```
df.groupby('logdate')[['Username']].count()
```

Any suggestions would be helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['logdate'],df['Username']).reset_index()
```

Comment: Worked, Thanks for introducing this function. I was pretty stuck on this.